# C++ Recursive Lambda Memory Usage

Tags: c++

I got a Wrong Answer at AtCoder, using Recursive Lambda dfs returning void, like this.

```cpp
  int dfs = y_combinator(
    [&](auto self, int cu, int pa = -1) -> int {
      dp[cu][0] = dp[cu][1] = 1;
      for(auto to: g[cu]){
        if(to != pa){
          self(to, cu);
          dp[cu][0] *= (dp[to][0] + dp[to][1]);
          dp[cu][1] *= dp[to][0];
        }
      }
      // return 0;
    }
  )(0);
```

Using too much memory (or another point?) seemed to be the reason of WA.

https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/submissions/31097803

But if I added return value, it resolved.

https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/submissions/31099529

What happened in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified a trailing return type for your lambda in both cases. Not returning an `int` makes your program ill-formed. Heed the compiler:

> warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

As well as that, adding `y_combinator_result` and `y_combinator` to `namespace std` is ill-formed (and pointless, as you have `using namespace std`'d them back into the global namespace)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I tried to use void type for the lambda...
Using void type also ill-formed?

Comment: @ekusiadadus you'd need to remove the `int dfs = ` for the void return.

Comment: @ekusiadadus which the compiler is recommending you do anyway, as it warns `dfs` is unused. `dfs` is also a strange name for the *result* of a search. Did it used to be `y_combinator dfs(...);`? (with a call elsewhere)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I resubmitted the code, modified with void. Function dfs() was unused. I forgot removing the function. (which I used to ensure my solution is correct..)

Comment: https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/submissions/31100435

Answer (score 1):

So what happens here is something I like to call "Compiler black Magic".
Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling.
Or mayby in your specific cases "Tail Recursion Transformation" or maybe "Tail Recursion Elimination".

Basically Compiler a magic things. They have allot of tricks of the trade to try and help speed up/shrink program binaries.

I put both version of your submersion into the website called godbolt.org see https://godbolt.org/z/69KP5oh8r
Without the return statement the compiler just implements the recursive function in a very straight forward manor.

However with the return function in there it does "magic".
It does not eliminate the recursive call its still in there but it adds allot of extra code before and after that recursive call.

Compiler's have allot of tricks that can help you're code run faster.
However it generally stops helping you if you start doing "ill-formed behavior".
In your case its creating a function which your promise will return a int.
then when you don't return a int its algorithm's might fail you.

For example if you hade done this.

```
 y_combinator(
    [&](auto self, int cu, int pa = -1) -> void  {
      dp[cu][0] = dp[cu][1] = 1;
      for(auto to: g[cu]){
        if(to != pa){
          self(to, cu);
          dp[cu][0] *= (dp[to][0] + dp[to][1]);
          dp[cu][1] *= dp[to][0];
        }
      }
    }
  )(0);
```

You get the same result as retuning zero.
Hopefully this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Your code really works...
I shouldn't have got value from the lambda!

Comment: It's not really compiler magic. Undefined behaviour is undefined. OP is *lucky* they got runtime errors.

Comment: And the actual mechanism of failure is most likely the call site popping a value off the stack when the function didn't push anything, i.e. removing some other value

Comment: @Caleth That mechanism makes more sense when looking at again from godbolt.org
I assumed he got run time errors because he reach his recursion depth in his UB version of his code. And the other version the compiler optimized away a big portion of the recursion calls. Giving him no errors. But yeah stack popping might have been it